# Aborting jenkins pipline project from shell stage

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to abort the jenkins pipline project from the stage which executes the if else shell condition. I want to abort the jenkins build when the if condition is executed.

below is the stage code.

```
        stage('stage: Abort check'){
        steps{
            script{
                sh '''
                    if [ `ls ${DIR} | wc -l` -ge 8 ] ; then
                        echo "More then 5 card definition applications are running. Delete Few applications"\n
                        echo "ABORTING the JOB"
                        currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                    else
                        echo "Less then 5 card definition applications are running. Excecuting remaining stages"
                    fi;

                '''
            }
        }
    }
```

I have used the declarative command `currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'` but this cant be used in the shell block.

I am getting `currentBuild.result: not found` error

Can anyone please guide me to know how these can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of your shell there's no currentBuild, you have it in the context of your jenkins pipeline.

You have to rely on output of your sh commands and do `currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'` outside `sh '''`.

```
steps{
    script{
        def res = 0
        res = sh(script: '''
                if [ `ls ${DIR} | wc -l` -ge 8 ] ; then
                    echo "More then 5 card definition applications are running. Delete Few applications"\n
                    echo "ABORTING the JOB"
                    exit 1
                else
                    echo "Less then 5 card definition applications are running. Excecuting remaining stages"
                    exit 0
                fi;
            '''
                  , returnStatus:true)
        if (res != 0) {
          currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the build is now aborting on else statement as well which I don't want it. Can you please help me with that as well?